# Is it possible to harness an application without COM?

Tags: c#, vba, shell, com

I've created a .Net app, hosted on a secure sharepoint. I want to be able to run this app via VBA (or other apps).

Through asking and research yesterday, I found this is easy to do via `Shell filePath, vbNormalFocus` - and I can even pass arguments to the app, but what I really want is to control the app as an object, similar to controlling a COM object. After researching and much confusion today I found I can't use COM because this isn't a class library - it's an .exe app (although I've learned SO much today!)

Imagine this type of deal:

```
Dim x as Object
Set x = Shell "filePath", vbNormalFocus
    x.NotSureHowThisWorks
```

I want to start the app in my Excel environment, and make many calls to and from the app, to give it instructions. The calls could be strings or whatever but the point is I need the running app coupled to an object variable in the VBA code so I can repeat calls and receive responses.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you imagine that you wrote "MS Word" and you control it from Excel through VBA, changing its caption, writing and reading from it, would that be an answer of your question?

Comment: I don't know how MS apps work. They're installed on a user's computer and the libraries are all hosted on the user's computer. I can create class libraries and get them on a user's computer through an installer, but I can't create COM interopability for an app, never mind one hosted online? Is there some way I can instantiate an .exe app from an online URL yet have COM interops?

Comment: Sounds like you want to treat an exe as you would a referenced type library. You can't do that, the .exe is running in its own separate process. The `Shell` call is just invoking the command-line entry point. Now that last comment changes things. If the app isn't a local .exe but some sandboxed web application, then you need to look into whether it has an API and, if not, you need to look into browser automation. Wildly different approaches for wildly different things. Please clarify what "app" stands for.

Comment: The app is an .exe that I am hosting on a SharePoint online. I don't have capacity to host a web service or web app. I'm literally calling the online .exe (with server-connectivity) from vba  in excel deployed to users.

Comment: Make your .net app COM-visible and expose a COM-visible entry point, register for COM interop for late-binding, instantiate the app in VBA.

Comment: That's what I tried but someone told me I can't do that for an .exe, only for class libraries. I tried `COM-visible` and deploying app through an installer, but not sure how to expose an entry-point (and I think registering for COM interop is taken care of by installer - it does for class libraries anyway)

Comment: It should be rather trivial to organize your .net solution so that the .exe project references a class library project that exposes the API that both VBA and .NET can use...

Comment: You'd think... I may have missed something very obvious. I'll try again because I tried the answer supplied by @this below earlier and couldn't figure it. I think I might have been trying too hard.

Comment: But even if I manage to do this, how can I harness a specific instance of my solution that resides online? Or is this something I maybe need to write methods for within the library...

Answer (score 2):

Since the app is yours, the most simplest thing you can do is to break your app into 2 projects; one DLL and one EXE project. Have the EXE project reference the DLL for all the functionalities, and make the DLL COM-visible then just reference that DLL from your COM application.

If it's meant to be a shared process, then it might be simpler to just run it as a service rather than an .exe.

Comment: I tried this also earlier today - so I can get the references to the .dll working fine in a VBA project, but not sure how to create an instance of the .exe that then uses all the methods in the .dll!? I must be missing something incredibly simple here!

Comment: @jamheadart have both projects in the same solution, make the executable project reference the type library project

Comment: I will try again, honestly when I crack this I will kick myself for making it so complicated.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure this makes sense for my question. Even if I get to expose some methods in the app through a class library, how do I then create an instance of the app from a URL in particular? E.g. for MSWord I write "x = New Word.Application" but for my .exe I want "x = New MyApp("locationOfExe")